# Load js with Ajax in a script tag

Tags: javascript, ajax, load

Hello everyone.
Here's my problem: I have a script (ajax) that load a file that contains js with php.
I managed to load it in a  tag with a id="test" like this:

```
function fun()
{
 var ddl = document.getElementById("page");
 var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
 var ddl2 = document.getElementById("zone");
 var selectedValue2 = ddl2.options[ddl2.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue !== "" && selectedValue2 !== "")
   {

        $("#test").load('optimisation/run.php?page='+selectedValue+'&zone='+selectedValue2+'');

   }
}
```

But the problem is, I already have  tags in my loaded file, so I end up with:

```
<script id="test>
<script>
// MY CODE
</script>
</script>
```

Any idea on how to delete the script with the id after the load is finished?

Comment: And why you have `<script id="test">` instead of for example `<div id="test">`?

Comment: Will it work with a div?

Comment: Yes, you can. Actually to any block element or body or to head

Comment: Thank you it's working. ^^
But the problem is, the graph in the js file isn't loading. I've put an alert in it, and that's working. And when I use the script directly (without the load), it's working.

Comment: Do you have some live example?

Comment: No. I tried to do a fiddle but I can't make the ajax call (lack of a field), and I need a external chart.js file.